# Akka cluster error

Tags: scala, akka

Is it mandatory to use sbt for cluster usage in akka. I have tried to add a few jars to the classpath. While the compiling goes well, running the relevant class generates an error.

> scala -cp
>   ../akka-2.2.1/lib/akka/akka-cluster_2.10-2.2.1.jar:../akka-2.2.1/lib/akka/netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:../akka-2.2.1/lib/akka/akka-remote_2.10-2.2.1.jar:../akka-2.2.1/lib/akka/protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar:./
>   TransformationFrontend 2551

here's the issue encountered:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider.(java.lang.String,
>   akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings, akka.event.EventStream,
>   akka.actor.Scheduler, akka.actor.DynamicAccess)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2800)  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2043)

This is the official Akka cluster example. Can someone throw some light on my query?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is probably that you have an akka-actor.jar in your scala distributuion that is Akka 2.1.x and you're trying to use Akka 2.2.x.

You'll have to run your code by running the java command and add the scala-library.jar and the correct akka-actor.jar and typesafe-config.jar to the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Scala 2.10? This is the Scala version you need for Akka 2.2.

What does the following yield?

`scala -version`

It should show something like

`$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.10.3 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL`